# How to convert Hex color to Hex black and white?

Tags: css

I could use a program like GIMP and figure this out but I think it would be easier to just do the calculation manually, that is if I knew how.

If I have say:

```
#FF0000 (red)
```

how do I convert this to its black and white equivalent in HEX.

One guess would be to take the average of each RGB value, and apply to each color space.

So

```
(0xff + 0x00 + 0x00) / 3 = 255 / 3 = 85 = 0x55
```

would come to

```
#555555
```

Is this correct?  Its just a guess.

Comment: Yes. this is a correct way to do it.

Comment: 0xFF / 3 is no equal 256 >> 3, the >> is a bitwise operator it just shift the binary value of 256 3 bits right

Comment: @yep it is easier to convert to decimal and then divide.  shift operator works well if you divide by a factor of 2 ... updated.

Comment: What about this awesome CSS3 filer? http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/say-hello-to-css3-filters/

Comment: No, it's not the correct way to do it. Green is lighter than Blue and Red so they are not equal. You must convert each color separately. See my correct formula below.

Comment: as much to remind myself as anything: there's an interesting looking cli "util for doing hex math quickly": https://github.com/vapier/pcalc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting to [Y'UV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV), and taking the Y' component would be a much more accurate representation for the gray scale value of an RGB value. I am aware that the conversion formula is different for video compression between compressing HD (720p) resolution video, and Full HD (1080p) resolution video. So the conversion to gray scale is not exactly trivial to figure out. There seems to be some human element involved in deciding how gray full bright red is.

Anyways, assuming `col` is your initial colour value, the formula you are looking for is this:

```
(((((((col >> 16) & 0xff)*76) + (((col >> 8) & 0xff)*150) +
((col & 0xff)*29)) >> 8)) << 16) |

(((((((col >> 16) & 0xff)*76) + (((col >> 8) & 0xff)*150) + 
((col & 0xff)*29)) >> 8)) << 8) | 

((((((col >> 16) & 0xff)*76) + (((col >> 8) & 0xff)*150) + 
((col & 0xff)*29)) >> 8))
```

Incidentally, your #FF0000 comes out to be #4B4B4B using this formula.

Comment: that is very complicated.  Can you break down what this is doing conceptually or provide a reference?  i.e. weighted average, etc.  Does this video transformation apply to image transformations?

Comment: (col >> 16) & 0xff, (col >> 8) & 0xff, col & 0xff breaks the rgb value down into their red green and blue components. The 76, 150 and 29 numbers come from the wikipedia article in the link. Finally, the left shifts by 16, 8 and 0 (although you don't see this zero) together with the bit-wise or "|" re-assembles the value back into an rgb value.

Comment: I wonder if (and how) this can be used in a script to convert full-color SVG files to monochrome?

Answer (score 3):

How to convert HEX color to HEX greyscale:

1. convert HEX to RGB
2. R = Red value, G = Green value, B = Blue value, X = Grayscale value
3. So we know R, G & B, we need to workout X
4. To do this we use this formula...

   **X = (0.58 x R) + (0.17 x G) + (0.8 x B)**
5. The gray-scale RGB value is R=X,G=X,B=X
6. Convert back to HEX

If we apply this formula to your #FF0000 color the output is #949494.
If you open Photoshop the conversion is the same (depending on your color preferences). I've also tested it for many other mixed colors and the conversion is an exact match to Photoshop.

How did I get these values?

Well if you open Photoshop, create a dot of Red, Green & Blue and convert to grey-scale then use the eye-drop to test the converted colors, the values are as shown in my formula.

Now you can use this formula in your script to auto convert to grey-scale!

Comment: I'm curious to know where the value of those multipliers come from?

Comment: They came from tests I performed using Photoshop. RGB>Grayscale
The solution is tested and 100% matches the output from Photoshop. It's also used in a solution I developed a while back.
I hope this helps and you find this solution useful.

Comment: White is -> 255 * .58 + .17 * 255 + 255 * .8 = 395.25 which is greater than 255. How are those multipliers used?

Answer (score 3):

Going off user1637281's answer, the Y'UV method is good, but he chose the wrong multipliers, assuming your color is an RGB hex code. Here are the correct multipliers from that same [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Conversion_to.2Ffrom_RGB).

```
int ConvertToBlackAndWhite(int col)
{
    int r = col >> 16;
    int g = (col >> 8) & 0xff;
    int b = col & 0xff;
    int bnw = int(r * 0.299 + g * 0.587 + b * 0.114) & 0xff;
    return (bnw << 16) | (bnw << 8) | bnw;
}
```

Another option is to simply average the three values, which is what your original question looks to be doing.

```
int bnw = int((r + g + b) / 3) & 0xff;
```

The method that uses Y' will actually end up pretty close to simply averaging them most of the time, but will end up with higher contrast between colors. For example, if you just average the 3 values, 0xFF0000, 0x00FF00, and 0x0000FF will all look the same.

Comment: .299+.587+.114 = 1 that checks out